# Resized partition is not recognizing new space

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, gpt, ext4

I'm migrating from a 250GB SSD to a 1TB SSD, but after cloning and resizing the root partition the volume still only shows the original partition size.  Here are the steps I took:

First, cloning the drive:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=64M conv=sync,noerror status=progress
```

Next, I used `parted` to resize the partition:

```
$ sudo parted
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) select /dev/sdc
Using /dev/sdc
(parted) unit B
(parted) resizepart 4 1000204869119                                       
(parted) print
Model: ATA WDC WDBNCE0010P (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000204886016B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start       End             Size           File system     Name    Flags
 1      1048576B    3145727B        2097152B                       grub    bios_grub
 2      3145728B    137363455B      134217728B     ext2            boot    boot, esp
 3      137363456B  674234367B      536870912B     linux-swap(v1)  swap
 4      674234368B  1000204869119B  999530634752B  ext4            rootfs

(parted) quit
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

Booting into new drive and running `df -h` yielding disappointing values, with the root fs (/dev/sda4) still only showing 228G as the volume size:

```
$ sudo df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             10M  4.0K   10M   1% /dev
/dev/sda4       228G  228G     0 100% /
tmpfs           789M  2.3M  787M   1% /run
cgroup_root      10M     0   10M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm             3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2       124M   70M   49M  59% /boot
```

Running `lshw` to verify the drive:

```
 *-scsi:0
      physical id: 0
      logical name: scsi0
      capabilities: emulated
    *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: WDC  WDBNCE0010P
         vendor: Western Digital
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sda
         version: 00WD
         serial: 19243F448513
         size: 931GiB (1TB)
         capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
         configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=054e688b-70a8-4ffd-8226-1bc6b75b2a28 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
       *-volume:0
            description: BIOS Boot partition
            vendor: EFI
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sda1
            serial: 468b2294-12d4-441f-8c64-d256156a2de3
            capacity: 2047KiB
            capabilities: nofs
            configuration: name=grub
       *-volume:1
            description: System partition
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sda2
            logical name: /boot
            version: 1.0
            serial: cd85570b-2031-47e9-87f8-d4c940a40945
            size: 128MiB
            capabilities: boot extended_attributes large_files ext2 initialized
            configuration: filesystem=ext2 modified=2019-07-31 09:37:36 mount.fstype=ext2 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl name=boot state=mounted
       *-volume:2
            description: Linux swap volume
            physical id: 3
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
            logical name: /dev/sda3
            version: 1
            serial: cb02e96e-b1ae-4b38-b86d-bd79034b5ced
            size: 511MiB
            capacity: 511MiB
            capabilities: swap initialized
            configuration: filesystem=swap name=swap pagesize=4095
       *-volume:3
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 4
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
            logical name: /dev/sda4
            logical name: /
            logical name: /var/lib/docker
            version: 1.0
            serial: ed921b41-8b1a-4199-b6cb-d062e2b0eb13
            size: 232GiB
            capacity: 930GiB
            capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2007-02-01 07:27:38 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2017-08-19 23:06:44 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,noatime,data=ordered mounted=2019-07-31 09:37:35 name=rootfs state=mounted
```

I notice that volume 3 lists the following:

```
    size: 232GiB
    capacity: 930GiB
```

Next, I run `e2fsck`, but I'm not sure what else I can do (removed the original drive making `sdc` now `sdb`).

```
$ sudo e2fsck -vf /dev/sdb4
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 991031 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 11797848 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes
Pass 1E: Optimizing extent trees
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sdb4: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

     5025939 inodes used (33.00%, out of 15228928)
       30101 non-contiguous files (0.6%)
        1926 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 4828038/4154/9
    60848819 blocks used (99.94%, out of 60884782)
           0 bad blocks
           4 large files

     4354526 regular files
      465207 directories
        1080 character device files
         523 block device files
          22 fifos
       22888 links
      204492 symbolic links (192025 fast symbolic links)
          80 sockets
------------
     5048818 files
```

Checking with `lsblk`:

```
$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0     2M  0 part
├─sdb2   8:18   0   128M  0 part
├─sdb3   8:19   0   512M  0 part
└─sdb4   8:20   0 930.9G  0 part
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the last (and most gratifying) step - growing the filesystem. This can be done online with a command like resize2fs /dev/sdb4  (Some distros use resize4fs for the same tool)

Comment: That did it!  haha.  Thank you so much.  Amazing that something so simple resolved a world of headache!  :)